# Spring testing postmapping with params

Tags: java, spring, mockito

Can anyone tell me how to test this specified method in my controller using Mockito

```
@RequestMapping(value = "categories", params = {"save"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String newCategory(@Valid Category category){
        categoriesService.save(category);
        return "redirect:categories";
    }
```

I'm trying to do this this way, but I'm getting HTTP status code 400 instead of 302 and I don't know how to create correct request to test this mapping

```
this.mockMvc
                .perform(post("/categories")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
                        .sessionAttr("category", new Category()))
                .andExpect(status().isFound())
                .andExpect(redirectedUrl("categories"));
```

EDIT

OK, I have changed my test to this form, and it's working now for me.

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        params.add("name", "test");
        params.add("save", "save");
        this.mockMvc
                .perform(post("/manager/categories")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
                        .params(params))
                .andExpect(status().isFound())
                .andExpect(redirectedUrl("categories"));
```

Comment: And is your `new Category()` actually valid?

Comment: Yes, it is valid

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think that the problem is in this piece of code `params={"save"}`, I don't know how to send this parameter to controller